# jQuery on() not working

Tags: jquery

I have the below code that is animating a div (#feedback-form-container) to slide in and out and when clicked it jumps to the center of the screen and then these slide animations are turned off. Once the form in the div is submitted and the form goes back to where it was I want to turn these animations back on again however this is not working. I am trying to use on() for this without success. Can anybody spot the problem? I'm stumped.

```
/////////////////////feedback form animation//////////////////////
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //find center of screen
  var $screenwidth = $(window).width();
  var $screencenter = $screenwidth / 2 - 177;
  var $startpos = $screencenter + 260;
  var overlay = jQuery('<div id="simpleoverlay"> </div>');

  //hover to slide functions
  $('div#feedback-form-container').hover(function() {
    $('div#feedback-form-container').animate({
      left: '+=260px'
    },
    '2000');
  },

  function() {
    $('div#feedback-form-container').animate({
      left: '-=260px'
    },
    '6000');

  });
  //click to slide to center of screen
  $('div#feedback-form-container').click(function() {
    $('div#feedback-form-container').animate({
      left: '+=' + $screencenter
    },
    {
      duration: '2000',
      easing: 'swing',
      complete: setTimeout(function() {
        overlay.appendTo(document.body)
      },
      500)
    });

    //unbind functions
    if ($('div#feedback-form-container').is(':animated')) $('div#feedback-form-container').off('click').off('hover');
    //set cursor back to default
    $('div#feedback-form-container').css('cursor', 'default');

  });

  $('#wpcf7-f52-t1-o1').submit(function() {

    $('div#feedback-form-container').animate({
      left: '-=' + $startpos
    },
    '6000');

    $('div#feedback-form-container').on('hover').on('click');
  });
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? `version added: 1.7` [***See API***](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: you need to include your event handler in the `.on(...` statement. See http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: _"I am trying to use on() for this without success."_ - Did you look at the documentation for `.on()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `on` and `off` methods are not used to turn events on and off, despite the somwhat confusing names. The `on` method is used to bind events, and the `off` method is used to unbind events.

When you unbind an event, it's gone from the element. To use the event again you have to bind it again, and for that you have to specify what event handler you want to use for it. It's not enough to just specify the event, because the element doesn't remember the event handler from before.

Using `.click(func)` has the same effect as using `.on('click', func)`.

Comment: +1. Note also that the `.on()` code is inside a `.submit()` handler, so even with correct use of `.on()` possibly the page is being reloaded by the form submit?

Comment: Thank everyone I'm pretty new to this. I have read the on() documentation and modified the code a little but now getting an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: hoveranim is not defined". hoveranim is what I have named the function and tried to call to bind the event back on. Like this:

  $('div#feedback-form-container').on('hover', hoveranim())
    });

Comment: @user1837290: Then there is likely a scope problem. Are you perhaps using a function expression instead of a function statement? E.g. `$(...).click(function hoveranim() { ... });`. Then the function name is only known inside the function itself. Also note that you shouldn't use the parentheses when binding the event: ` $('div#feedback-form-container').on('hover', hoveranim);`.